# Can I configure Tridion to publish to one context but write internal links as a different context?

Tags: 2011, configuration, linking

Can I configure Tridion to publish to one context (eg `/myApp`) but write internal links as a different context (eg `/myAppBeta/myApp`)?  I'm hoping to do this by config not code if possible.

I have a Tridion website that runs at a context path in IIS, like

```
[IIS]/myApp
```

A 'beta' version of this website has now been deployed, and due to various constraints (including the old site is still running at `domain.com/myApp`) the beta version has to run at a URL like

```
domain.com/myAppBeta/myApp
```

with HTTP rewrites mapping `domain.com/myAppBeta` to the root of IIS. (so `domain.com/myAppBeta/myApp` resolves to `[IIS]/myApp`)

My problem is that Tridion writes and publishes internal links as `/myApp/path/to/page`.  This URL will not be caught by the HTTP rewrite rule, and will result in a 404 response from the existing site (still running at `domain.com/myApp`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this should be possible,  Tridion allows you to do a lot in terms of path configuration:

Publication settings
Inside here you can configure your publish path e.g /appBeta/app

Deployer
In the storage_conf.xml file in your deployer you can specify the file system path, for example c:/webapps - combined above the publication would publish to c:/webapps/appBeta/app

Here you could have another deployer which pushes to c:/webapps/xyz publishing to this 'target' would give you files located at c:/webapps/xyz/appBeta/app

This should offer some flexible storage options to which you can point IIS too.

Another useful suggestion is the cd_link_conf.xml, this allows you specify pre fixed to URLS returned via content delivery.

Hope this helps with your set up

Comment: Thanks John, I've set Publication settings > Publication URL to `/myAppBeta/myApp`.  Now when I republish the navigation, links are written as `myAppBeta/myApp/path/to/page`.  And most dynamic links are updated as I republish their targets.  However it looks like this change isn't affecting some dynamic content delivered through content broker - we have some custom code to render broker links, I'll have to look at that I guess.

Comment: Great, glad to help, i'd recommend republishing the content again, this will likely fix your link issues.

Comment: Haha - "republish your content" is the the Tridion version of "turn it off and on again", and it still gets me every time.

Comment: My broker content is now showing up as expected, but I'm still having problems with binaries/multimedia.  I've set the 'Images URL' on the publication to `/myAppBeta/myApp/Multimedia`, but links to PDF docs are still rendering as eg. `/myApp/Multimedia/doc.pdf`.

Comment: Update: My PDF doc links are working again :) Turns out there were some custom TBBs that had the multimedia URL-path hardcoded as `/myApp/Multimedia/`.  The code now references `Publication.MultimediaURL` which is better, but probably still unnecessary - all other URLs are written correctly without explicitly referencing Publication metadata in custom code.